# How to report background worker progress with only percentage on a label without progress bar

Tags: vb.net

Using the `BackgroundWorker Class` I need to run a process which extracts data from a database and report progress as percentage completed on a label without progress bar.

Most of the examples I have seen for this approach uses a loop in the `ProgressChanged Event` which makes the process to repeat:

For example:
Calling the code as shown below causes multiple calls to the DB, thus repeating the query.

```
Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, _

ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
        If (worker.CancellationPending = True) Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        Else
            ' This method is rightfully called multiple times.
            GetDbDataHere()
            worker.ReportProgress(i * 10)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Report update here:

```
Private Sub backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles
 backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    resultLabel.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%")
End Sub
```

Without a progress bar, how can run the process and display the percentage completed but without calling the method being process by the BackgroundWorker multiple times?

Comment: You can't report progress that you can't measure. If you execute a single query against a database, can you measure the progress of that query? If so then you simply report what you measure.  If not then how can you possibly report it?

Comment: I am asking if there is an alternative to other than a loop. Now I do not think it's possible

Comment: Forget the loop.  A loop is a means to an end.  You need to think about what you need to achieve and then determine the best means to achieve that end.  Do you want to perform an operation multiple times? If not then why are you even considering loops?  You want to perform an operation and if you want to be able to report on the progress of that operation then you need to be able to measure that progress. Can you measure the progress of a single query against a database?  That is the question that you need to answer. If the answer is yes, then you need to determine how.